# Oracle LIKE returns (ORA01722)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have got an ID field with IDs (varchar2) like U123JAS and P239BB.

During my query I perform a like filter:

```
ID LIKE ('U20Q%') //works perfectly.
```

but: when i do:

```
ID LIKE ('U20%') //it fails
```

ErrorCode

```
[Error Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Why?

*SOLUTION:*

The Error was caused by (tadaa) an invalid number cast in a totally different column.
The DataRow which was causing the error only hit the second like.

Thank you all for your help, may my failure help someone else in future :D

Comment: Are you sure that 1. ID is of VARCHAR2 type and 2. this is the actual query bit that fails? Can you post the whole query?

Comment: ID is Varchar2 and if I toggle the two examples, the whole query works with the first, but i doent with the second. 
I cant Post the whole query, sorry.
@Benoit

Comment: An German Page is mentioning an ORACLE TO_NUMBER function... 
https://oraculix.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/immer-wieder-ora-01722-invalid-number/ 
is that possible?

Comment: What happens if you remove the useless brackets and run it like this: `LIKE 'U20%'`. How do you run these statements? SQL*Plus? SQLDeveloper?

Comment: leaving out the brackets didn't change anything.
I am using DBVisualizer and recheck that in an php Oracle Query.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and the problem was because my table had a virtual column with a field value as `to_number(.....)` and a single record in that table violates the to_number function. I was very confused but, this question and solution saved my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is a number conversion somewhere else in your query. It's simply not evaluated in the first case, because the row that triggers the error hasn't id beginning with `U20Q`, but has id beginning with `U20`.

When it's necessary to convert the number, in the second case, you have a row for which it fails.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1 < dummy AND 1 = 0; /* works */

SELECT * FROM dual WHERE 1 < dummy AND 1 = 1; /* ORA-01722 */
```

Comment: @Harry: because the row that fails has id beginning with U20 (and the next character if any is not Q)